# Allocating variable at specific memory region at specific address in single header file

Tags: memory, static, volatile, shared, bare-metal

I am developing a bare-metal dual-core application in which I have an application running on Core 0 (a lwIP application) and another one running on Core 1.
I also have some shared flags to be read by both cores. In order to manage the DDR memory, I thought of including in the linker.ld script an additional memory region like this:

```
MEMORY
{
   ps7_ddr_0 : ORIGIN = 0x100000, LENGTH = 0x500000
   ps7_ddr_shared : ORIGIN = 0x700000, LENGTH = 0x500000
   ps7_qspi_linear_0 : ORIGIN = 0xFC000000, LENGTH = 0x1000000
   ps7_ram_0 : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x30000
   ps7_ram_1 : ORIGIN = 0xFFFF0000, LENGTH = 0xFE00
}

[...]

SECTIONS
{
.ps7_ddr_shared :
  {
    *(.ps7_ddr_shared)
  } > ps7_ddr_shared

...

}
```

The memory section is properly seen by the ARM compiler as I'm able to get information on that through the `size` tool.
However, when trying to place a specific variable at a specific address, it seems that not always the tools properly accounts for the variable size stored in the memory. In particular, I want the variables to be defined in a single header file to be included by both applications.

I tried the following approaches

**1. Defining the variables as pointer values**

```
#define MY_VAR (*(int*) 0x700000)
```

This works, and I can read and write the variable simply with

```
MY_VAR = 4;
```

However, running the `size` command returns:

```
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
       ps7_ddr_0:     4250944 B         5 MB     81.08%
  ps7_ddr_shared:          0 GB         5 MB      0.00%
ps7_qspi_linear_0:          0 GB        16 MB      0.00%
       ps7_ram_0:          0 GB       192 KB      0.00%
       ps7_ram_1:          0 GB      65024 B      0.00%
```

So it seems the variable is not accounted for, and it seems logical since I didn't actually declare any variable.

**2. Using compiler directives with `__attribute__`**

```
volatile int MY_VAR __attribute__((section('.ps7_ddr_shared'));
```

This approach fails because when including the header multiple times in multiple translation units to be linked together, I get an error of multiple definitions.
This also applies to the variants:

```
volatile int MY_VAR __attribute__((at(0x700000));
```

```
volatile int MY_VAR __attribute__((section('.ps7_ddr_shared'), at(0x700000);
```

So I'm not able to link - at all.

**3. Using compiler directives and `static` attribute**

```
static volatile int MY_VAR __attribute__((section('.ps7_ddr_shared'));
```

```
static volatile int MY_VAR __attribute__((section('.ps7_ddr_shared'), at(0x700000));
```

These approaches works and I'm seeing the variable(s) properly accounted for:

```
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
       ps7_ddr_0:     4250944 B         5 MB     81.08%
  ps7_ddr_shared:          12 B         5 MB      0.00%
ps7_qspi_linear_0:          0 GB        16 MB      0.00%
       ps7_ram_0:          0 GB       192 KB      0.00%
       ps7_ram_1:          0 GB      65024 B      0.00%
```

However, this doesn't work if I use

```
static volatile int MY_VAR __attribute__((at(0x700000));
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to understand that, since the MY_VAR variable is placed at 0x700000, it belongs to the .ps7_ddr_shared memory region?

Moreover, **what are the implications of using the `static` attribute when also assigning the `volatile` one and setting a specific memory location for the variable?** I know that defining static variables allows me to include the declaration multiple times because each TU sees its copy of the variable. But what does this mean if I set a specific memory region? These copies eventually refer to the exact same memory representation, so what is the meaning of 'copies' here?